# aiohttp - Got more than 8190 bytes (xxxx) when reading Header value is too long

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, aiohttp

The ClientSession responses on aiohttp are limited to 8190 bytes. I have requests that exceed that limit.
On the server make_handler configuration there is a max_field_size to increase that limit. Is there an analogous setting on the Client side?

Comment: Diego, Were you able to figure it out? I am also having same situation and want to know how can we increase the limit in ClientSession?